# How to transfer id from one table to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

There are two tables in the database,
the first is "projects"
the second is "company"

[image]

When creating a project, I select a company and send the id of this company to the "projects" table

In the second, the company name and a link to the logo

[image]

But, when I create a project, choosing a customer company, all logos are displayed ...

[image]

```js
const onGetCompanyListDetails = () => {
      return projectsList.map(projects => {
        const logoUrl = companyList.find(i => i.id === projects.companyId).imgUrl;
        return <img key={projects.id} src={logoUrl} />
      });
};
```

Comment: The code you posted basically shows the logo of every project. `projectsList.map` means to "translate" every element of `projectsList` &mdash; thus every "project" &mdash; with the given function, which returns the image node for every project given to it. I suppose the surrounding code contains a variable that stores the current project in the iteration, and the code should be modified to filter or compute based on it.

Comment: Using map returns an array so maybe you should use smt which does not, can you try using forEach instead of using map ?

Comment: @SüleymanGÜNDÜZ forEach returns `undefined`, so no logo would show up.

Comment: Eap, forEach return empty...

Comment: How do we know the selected company id?

Comment: when creating a project, I write the identifier to the database, to the table "projects"> "cjmpanyId"